# Ubuntu 18.04.3: Need help with ROCm tensorflow: Build error

Tags: 18.04, amdgpu-pro, tensorflow

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04.3 and I am trying to install tensorflow-rocm (for AMD GPU) version 1.14.0.

default pip3 install tensorflow-rocm is installing v2.0 but the code set that I use was made on 1.14, so there are some errors when I try to run the same on v2.0 mostly because of how packages have been moved.

So I found the source code of tensorflow-rocm v 1.14.0 but when I am trying to build it, I am facing an error. I have no idea why. I checked if rocm is installed on my system and as per their official site it is installed.

The error that I am facing is as follows:

```
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: Skipping '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package': error loading package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package': Encountered error while reading extension file 'rocm/build_defs.bzl': no such package '@local_config_rocm//rocm': Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/heyitsabi/tensorflow-upstream/third_party/gpus/rocm_configure.bzl", line 861
        _create_local_rocm_repository(repository_ctx)
    File "/home/heyitsabi/tensorflow-upstream/third_party/gpus/rocm_configure.bzl", line 682, in _create_local_rocm_repository
        make_copy_dir_rule(repository_ctx, name = "rccl-inclu...", <2 more arguments>)
    File "/home/heyitsabi/tensorflow-upstream/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 923, in make_copy_dir_rule
        _read_dir(repository_ctx, src_dir)
    File "/home/heyitsabi/tensorflow-upstream/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 956, in _read_dir
        _execute(repository_ctx, ["find", src_dir, ..."], ...)
    File "/home/heyitsabi/tensorflow-upstream/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 887, in _execute
        auto_configure_fail("\n".join([error_msg.strip() if ... ""]))
    File "/home/heyitsabi/tensorflow-upstream/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 324, in auto_configure_fail
        fail(("\n%sCuda Configuration Error:%...)))

Cuda Configuration Error: Repository command failed
find: ‘/opt/rocm/rccl/include’: No such file or directory

WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: error loading package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package': Encountered error while reading extension file 'rocm/build_defs.bzl': no such package '@local_config_rocm//rocm': Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/heyitsabi/tensorflow-upstream/third_party/gpus/rocm_configure.bzl", line 861
        _create_local_rocm_repository(repository_ctx)
    File "/home/heyitsabi/tensorflow-upstream/third_party/gpus/rocm_configure.bzl", line 682, in _create_local_rocm_repository
        make_copy_dir_rule(repository_ctx, name = "rccl-inclu...", <2 more arguments>)
    File "/home/heyitsabi/tensorflow-upstream/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 923, in make_copy_dir_rule
        _read_dir(repository_ctx, src_dir)
    File "/home/heyitsabi/tensorflow-upstream/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 956, in _read_dir
        _execute(repository_ctx, ["find", src_dir, ..."], ...)
    File "/home/heyitsabi/tensorflow-upstream/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 887, in _execute
        auto_configure_fail("\n".join([error_msg.strip() if ... ""]))
    File "/home/heyitsabi/tensorflow-upstream/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 324, in auto_configure_fail
        fail(("\n%sCuda Configuration Error:%...)))

Cuda Configuration Error: Repository command failed
find: ‘/opt/rocm/rccl/include’: No such file or directory

INFO: Elapsed time: 2.470s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
    currently loading: tensorflow/tools/pip_package
```

[Source site of tensorflow-rcom 1.14.0](https://github.com/ROCmSoftwarePlatform/tensorflow-upstream/blob/develop-upstream/rocm_docs/tensorflow-build-from-source.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying to find answers for hours, I finally found the rccl library(if that's what it is called) If this was a requirement mentioned on ROCm install guide I would have known.. sadly either I completely missed this or it is not there.

cloned it from git

and then used

```
sudo ./install.sh -i
```

Now my tensorflow package is being made. If any other error arises it will most likely for other reasons than the issue posted above, so I am sharing this answer.

btw normal ./install.sh -i ended up with an error saying it could not make the required files because it didn't have access, so I had to use sudo.

[RCCL package](https://github.com/ROCmSoftwarePlatform/rccl)